# Have RStudio use .Rd documentation files outside a package

Tags: r, rstudio, documentation, roxygen2

I created the following function to document functions in an RStudio project which is not a package:

```
library(stringr)
library(pbapply)
library(readr)

generate_docs <- function(code_folder = 'R') {
    sourcefiles <- list.files(code_folder, '\\.R$', full.names = TRUE)
    
    if (!dir.exists('man')) dir.create('man')
    
    pblapply( sourcefiles, function(sourcefile) {
        source_env = roxygen2::env_file(sourcefile)
        rd_blocks = roxygen2::parse_file(sourcefile, source_env)
        help_topics = roxygen2::roclet_process(roxygen2::rd_roclet(), rd_blocks, source_env, dirname(sourcefile))
        rd_code = lapply(help_topics, format)
        
        for (topic in names(rd_code)) {
            write_lines(rd_code[[topic]], file.path('man', topic))
        }
    })
    invisible()
}
```

The function produces the .Rd files correctly. But I wish RStudio to see these files and show the help page by pressing F1.

Is this possible?